# VS Test fail in Azure DevOps while all tests are sucessed

Tags: visual-studio, azure-devops, vstest, vstest.console

After we upgrade to VS2019 and use VS test task v2.0 in Azure DevOps, our test task keeps failing with the following message:

[image]

Our Visual Studio 2019 is version: 16.2.5

The task version is: Visual Studio Test 2.157.3

What's wrong with the VS test task?

Update, the error message is:

[error]Error: The process 'C:\BldWorkarea\SLB1_VSTS\ZhouShuRen_work_tasks\VSTest_ef087383-ee5e-42c7-9a53-ab56c98420f9\2.157.3\Modules\DTAExecutionHost.exe' failed with exit code 1

Comment: Please include the errors messages etc as TEXT not as a picture of the text. There are many reasons but they include the fact that we cannot search within the image, and we cannot copy text from the image to use in searches etc. Please [edit] the question to include the text.

Answer (score 1):

> VS Test fail in Azure DevOps while all tests are sucessed

It seems the issue for the version of that VS test task. You can check the following ticket for some more details:

[VSTest 2.154.0\Modules\DTAExecutionHost.exe' failed with exit code 1](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/648503/vstest-21540modulesdtaexecutionhostexe-failed-with.html)

As workaround, you can switch the task back to `V1`.

Hope this helps.